# Creating a foreign key constraint with non-matching data

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, constraints, sql-server-2016

Greetings!

I have inserted data from sql insert files into an ms sql database. Apperantly this data is not fully complete.
I discovered this when I was trying to make the ERD and create key constraints between tables. 
When I try to connect article_review with order1 where order1 has a primary key and article review has a foreign key.

I have a query where it selects all records with non-matching key values:
see image:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6X7vG.jpg

So what I want to do now:
insert new rows into article_review with the missing ID values. The values of the other columns do not really matter, they can be NULL or random generated.

A simple join won't really cut it because all of the other columns are non-identical.

ps. all above is needed because ms sql 2016 wont let me create a key constraint between 2 tables where one of them contains a value that is not in the other one and thus throws the error:

```
'order1' table saved successfully
'article_review' table saved successfully
'review' table
- Unable to create relationship 'FK_review_order1'.  
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_review_order1". The conflict occurred in database "superDatabase", table "dbo.order1", column 'id'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to add the Foreign key for documentation only?

You could add the FK like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.order1 WITH NOCHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_review_order1 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES dbo.article_review (id)
```

note the **WITH NOCHECK**

This way the foreign key is created, but is not trusted and disabled, which can be seen with this query:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(fk.schema_id) AS sch, T.name,
        fk.name, is_disabled, is_not_trusted, fk.is_not_for_replication
FROM    sys.foreign_keys fk WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN sys.tables T WITH (NOLOCK) ON T.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
WHERE   fk.is_not_trusted = 1
        AND fk.is_disabled = 0
ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME(fk.schema_id), T.name, fk.name;
```

idea from https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/foreign-key-trusted/